# Convert a String JSON file to an enum case

Tags: json, swift

I have the object below:

```
class Food {
    var cal: Int
    var displayName: String
    var imgUrl: String
    var dishType: DishType

    init(cal: Int, displayName: String, imgUrl: String, dishType: DishType) {
        self.cal = cal
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.imgUrl = imgUrl
        self.dishType = dishtype
    }
}

enum DishType {
    case starter
    case main
    case desert
}
```

And this is a part of my Alamofire request:

```
if let cal = foodJson["cal"].int,
    let displayName = foodJson["display_name"].string,
    let dishType = foodJson["type"].string,
    let imgUrl = foodJson["imgUrl"].string {
    let food = Food(cal: cal, displayName: displayName, imgUrl: imgUrl, dishType: ??)

    foods.append(food)
```

How can I convert the Json String "dishType" into a "DishType" type I created with the enum in order to correctly fill my instance of Food?

Comment: Just use Codable, it takes care of enums automatically: https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Answer (score 19):

You might want to specify an associated value for your enum:

```swift
enum DishType: String {
    case starter = "starter"
    case main    = "main"
    case desert  = "desert"
}
```

Or, more simply:

```swift
enum DishType: String {
    case starter
    case main
    case desert
}
```

Then you can do:

```swift
dishType = DishType(rawValue: string)
```

e.g.

```swift
if let dishTypeString = foodJson["type"].string,
    let dishType = DishType(rawValue: dishTypeString) {
        …
}
```

---

Personally, if doing Swift 4, I'd retire `SwiftyJSON` and use the native `JSONDecoder` and declare your types to be `Codable`. (Note, we still need to define the `DishType` to have associated values, like above.)

For example, let’s imagine your response was something like:

```json
{
    "foods": [{
            "cal": 800,
            "display_name": "Beef",
            "imgUrl": "http://example.com/wheres_the_beef.jpg",
            "dishType": "main"
        },
        {
            "cal": 2000,
            "display_name": "Chocolate cake",
            "imgUrl": "http://example.com/yummy.jpg",
            "dishType": "desert"
        }
    ]
}
```

You could then define your types like so:

```swift
struct Food: Codable {
    let cal: Int
    let displayName: String
    let imgUrl: String
    let dishType: DishType
}

enum DishType: String, Codable {
    case starter
    case main
    case desert
}
```

And then you can parse the response like so:

```swift
struct FoodsResponse: Codable {
    let foods: [Food]
}

Alamofire.request(url)
    .responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let responseObject = try decoder.decode(FoodsResponse.self, from: data)
                
                print(responseObject.foods)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
}
```

This gets you completely out of the business of manually iterating through the results to map it to your objects.

Clearly, I assume your real response has more keys than just `foods`, so you'd add whatever fields you needed to `FoodsResponse`, but hopefully this illustrates the idea of letting `JSONDecoder` parse the JSON into your model structures automatically.

For more information about `JSONDecoder` and `Codable` types, see [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

---

By the way, my example `FoodResponse` structure prompted some question why I didn't just assume the web service would return an array of `Food` objects. Let me explain my rationale.

A more typical structure for `FoodsResponse` in a web service response would be something like:

```swift
struct FoodsResponse: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let error: String?   // only supplied if `success` was `false`
    let foods: [Food]?   // only supplied if `success` was `true`
}
```

In this structure, this response object can handle success scenarios, like:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "foods": […]
}
```

Or failures:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "No data found"
}
```

I think it best to have a structure that includes some common success `Boolean`, e.g. `success`, that all well-formed responses include, and then have various properties that are filled in for successes or failures, respectively.

---

It should be recognized that `Decodable` enumerations are a little brittle: If the backend introduces a new enumeration case, it can break the client code (throwing an unrecoverable error on decode). So in my projects, when integrating with a backend (esp one maintained by other developers), in my Swift code I have an `enum` that has an `unknown` case. And I support this with a custom decoder/encoder:

```swift
enum DishType: Codable, Equatable, Hashable {
    case starter
    case main
    case desert

    case unknown(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let mealType = try container.decode(String.self)

        switch mealType {
        case Self.starter.rawValue: self = .starter
        case Self.main.rawValue:    self = .main
        case Self.desert.rawValue:  self = .desert
        default:                    self = .unknown(mealType)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(rawValue)
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .starter:            "starter"
        case .main:               "main"
        case .desert:             "desert"
        case .unknown(let value): value
        }
    }
}
```

This is not as concise as a simple raw-representable `enum`, but it is more robust. The client can gracefully decode JSON that includes values other than the fixed list of values that it was anticipating. E.g., if the server adds a `salad` meal type, the above will not break.

Needless to say, one would want to issue a new release of the client app to gracefully support the new values, but this is a defensive programming technique that minimizes serious problems when the backend adds new enumeration values.

Comment: This was super helpful. "(rawValue: string)" in particular is what did it for me.